# How to transform columns of data with a specific transformation with mean and std

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and want to transform each column with a transformation:

```
def transformtanh(mean,odchyl):
    return 1/2*(tanh(0.01((x-mean)/odchyl))+1)
```

Now, I can evaluate mean and std of each column with:

```
mean=df.mean(axis=0)
odchyl=df.std(axis=0)
```

But how can I now use the transformtanh on each column with the corresponding mean and std?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `transform` with parameters,

```
import numpy as np

def custom_tanh(val, mean, std):
    return 1/2*(np.tanh(0.01*((val-mean)/std))+1)

df.transform(lambda x : custom_tanh(x, x.mean(), x.std()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function if you want to implement something in every column.

Try

```
new_df = df.apply(lambda x: 1/2*(tanh(0.01((x-mean)/odchyl))+1))
```

Comment: Thanks, but each column has a different mean and std, which I want to apply to a function

Comment: Maybe provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: Okay, I will add some. What I mean is that mean and odchyl is different for every column (not constant).